# How to show an html element from another page in my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry, I'm new in web developing so I don't have any idea this can be done or not.

There are two pages:

1. www.this-is-not-my-page.com
2. www.this-is-my-page.com

In 2nd page, is there any way to get any html tag's inside elements to my page ?

for example: the pattern of 1st page:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p class="sample">
        bla bla bla...
       </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

now, in 2nd page(which I'm creating), I want the content from **'p'** element with **"sample"** class(no need to get the class).

Can this be done, and if so, what do I need to know and where do I start?

Comment: [You can't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) with the tagged languages.

Comment: Here is not a place to provide the codes you order

Comment: You cannot do this unless CORS is used on the other domain or you use a proxy server script

Comment: @Mojtaba Cut the condescension. This is a suitable question for this format. The OP is not asking anyone to write his code. He is asking IF this can be done, and to give him somewhere to begin to figure out HOW. Nothing wrong with this question at all.

Comment: "Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol."

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't know that can't do it by js/jq..

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use `iframe`, i dont think this can be done with just javascript/jquery.

Although, if you use PHP, you can use the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm